# jQuery - How to select all elements with same Class but not with particular ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```
$( "#targetButton" ).click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: './checkcolors.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                url: 'http://www.sportsdirect.com/dunlop-mens-canvas-low-top-trainers-246046?colcode=24604622',
                SizeId: '6.5'
            },
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function (data) {
                var arr = data.split(',');
                arr.forEach(function(id){
                    $('#' + id.trim()).show();
                });
            }
        });
});
```

This is a ajax post function which is returning an number if ids.
The returned ids are answering to div html elements which i have to show.
These html div elements have same class but all of them are with different ids.

So i tried this code to select all elements with same class but excluding the elements with the pointed ids:

```
$('.ColorImagesNOColor:not(#' + id.trim() + ')').show();
```

It seems it is not working because it shows all elements with this class even with the ids which must NOT be shown.

Can you please help me out ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aLj9Ldne/1/ this piece of code work.
Check id.trim() in external variable

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it inside a `.forEach` loop. That means that the last `$('.ColorImagesNOColor:not(#' + id.trim() + ')').show();` will determine the final visibility of the `.ColorImagesNOColor` elements.

If you want to show all `.ColorImagesNOColor` elements and hide the ones with the id's returned, then you can move the first step to before the `.forEach` loop:

```
// Show all initially
$('.ColorImagesNOColor').show();

// Hide ones with certain Id's
arr.forEach(function(id){
    $('#' + id.trim()).hide();
});
```